# configure monitrc to monitor node js app process, can't find node app pidfile running with screen ec2 linux

Tags: node.js, linux, pid, gnu-screen, monit

I run my app.js (node js application) via screen on my ec2 linux instance.
I'm trying to config my monitrc file and I need the app pidfile.
It's not in : 
/var/run
(and there isn't a /var/www)

Would really appreciate it if someone has any idea where the pidfile is or how can I find it out..
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like there isn't a pid file created so I used forever-monitor in order to restart my app.js script in case of an error.
Looks like it is working.
What you need to do is npm install forever
and write server.js :

```
var forever = require('forever'),
    child = new(forever.Monitor)('app.js', {
        'silent': false,
        'pidFile': '/var/run/app.pid',
        'watch': false,
        'options': ['8383'],  // Additional arguments to pass to the script,
        'sourceDir': '.', // Directory that the source script is in
        'watchDirectory': '.',     // Top-level directory to watch from.
        'watchIgnoreDotFiles': true, // whether to ignore dot files
        'watchIgnorePatterns': [], // array of glob patterns to ignore, merged with contents of watchDirectory + '/.foreverignore' file
        'logFile': 'logs/forever.log', // Path to log output from forever process (when daemonized)
        'outFile': 'logs/forever.out', // Path to log output from child stdout
        'errFile': 'logs/forever.err'
    });
child.start();
forever.startServer(child);
```

and then run it with - node server.js (I run it from ~/nodejs directory)
Still the pid file that supposed to be in /var/run isn't there, weird but I don't need monit anymore.
I still don't understand why I should additionally use upstart (like all the posts related suggested) anyhow when I tried to run upstart it didn't work

Answer (score 5):

in your app you can get the current pid number with process.pid so

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/pidfile", process.pid);
```

and you get a pidfile in tmp

Comment: Maybe I don't understand well what you want but the pidfile is only a file with the pid number.

Comment: but the pid changes when the process restarts. anyhow that is what monitrc configuration requires. I have to give it pid file path.

Comment: There is nothing magical that creates pidfiles.  Many of the daemon scripts used for init (e.g. in /etc/init.d) have helper routines that create pid files.  In their absence you will have to write one yourself.

Comment: Thanks Joe, was a little strange get a down vote with a correct answer.